# How can I demangle the name in an RTTI Type Descriptor?

Tags: msvc, name-mangling

I'm currently browsing through RTTI information available in an MSVC++2003 executable (writing an IDAPython script to recreate structs for the class hierarchy). Apparently, as visualized [here](http://www.openrce.org/articles/img/igor2_rtti1.gif), the RTTI Type Descriptor stores something like the name of the classes or their constructor:

```
.?AVexception@@
    .?AUescaped_list_error@boost@@
    .?AVruntime_error@stlp_std@@
```

However, it sports a mangling scheme I do not recognize yet. The name starts with a `.` which, according to this [wiki](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling#Basic_Structure), is not even a valid start for a mangled MSVC name. IDA and [an online name demangler](http://demangler.com/) also cannot demangle these names. According [to these scripts](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/196) (s. ms_rtti4.idc) these should map to:

```
typeid(struct exception)
    typeid(struct boost::escaped_list_error)
    typeid(struct stlp_std::runtime_error)
```

I tried removing the leading dot to get a valid start at least, but it is still invalid. Quickly writing an overly simplistic python line to at least fix namespaced class names...

```
return "::".join(reversed(name[4:-2].split("@")))
```

...it of course fails with generic type names, as with these classes here:

```
ns::FunctionBase             (.?AVFunctionBase@ns@@)
    ns::Z::P6AXPAX::?$FunctionT  (.?AV?$FunctionT@P6AXPAX@Z@ns@@)
    ns::Z::P6AHH::?$FunctionT    (.?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHH@Z@ns@@)
    ns::Z::P6AHPB_W::?$FunctionT (.?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHPB_W@Z@ns@@)
    ns::Z::P6AHI::?$FunctionT    (.?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHI@Z@ns@@)
```

I noticed removing the `.?AU` or `.?AV` prefix from those yields kinda useful results (missing the namespace sadly):

```
FunctionT@ns@@
    FunctionT<void (__cdecl*)(void *)>
    FunctionT<int (__cdecl*)(int)>
    FunctionT<int (__cdecl*)(wchar_t const *)>
    FunctionT<int (__cdecl*)(unsigned int)>
```

...but again that one now doesn't work for non-generic names.

I wonder if the RTTI Type Descriptor name scheme is documented, or if there is logic turning this into an actual RTTI name I can demangle with the usual tools?

Comment: I think [CodeXplorers source code](https://github.com/REhints/BlackHat_2015/blob/master/CodeXplorer%20v2.0%20%5BBH%20Edition%5D/source%20code/HexRaysCodeXplorer/ObjectFormatMSVC.h) could contain some hint: but they annotate AV as function and AU as structure but that does not seem to match your example

Comment: That's interesting though, I found out (via Igor Skochinsky's RTTI scripts), that these type "names" are actually equivalent to `typeid(struct xyz)` as added to my question now. I found a way to abuse demangling a valid ctor from it and then stripping out the class name which I post as an answer for now.

Comment: Check out the clang for windows source code. They claim binary compatibility with msvc rtti iirc.

Comment: @mrexodia Interesting, I get back to it when working on this part of the script again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via [Igor Skochinsky's classic IDA RTTI scripts](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/196), I found out that the names I posted are equivalent to `typeid(struct xyz)` (as I've added to my question).

Abusing creating a valid mangled dtor name from a substring of them and then stripping the ctor parts from the result yields great class names.

Here's my Python script and the results:

```
def demangle(name):
    # Check if this even is a problematic typeid.
    if name.startswith(".?A"):
        # Remove the .?AU or .?AV prefix.
        name = name[4:]
        # Demangle it as a default public destructor call.
        dtor_name = "??1" + name + "QAE@XZ"
        name = your_default_msvc_demangler.demangle(dtor_name)
        # Strip destructor pre and suffixes again (accessor / cconv and parameter list).
        name = name[len("public: __thiscall "):name.rfind("(")]
        # Remove dtor name.
        parts = name.split("~")
        return parts[0][:-2]
    else:
        return your_default_msvc_demangler.demangle(name)
```

And here are sample results for the names given in my question:

```
exception
    boost::escaped_list_error
    stlp_std::runtime_error

ns::FunctionBase::FunctionBase
    ns::FunctionT<void (__cdecl *)(void *)>
    ns::FunctionT<int (__cdecl *)(int)>
    ns::FunctionT<int (__cdecl *)(wchar_t const *)>
    ns::FunctionT<int (__cdecl *)(unsigned int)>
```

Probably not very elegant, but working.

Answer (score 2):

vc++filt seems to demangle it

```
?AVexception@@
 ?? AVexception
?AUescaped_list_error@boost@@
 ?? boost::AUescaped_list_error
?AVruntime_error@stlp_std@@
 ?? stlp_std::AVruntime_error
?AUescaped_list_error@boost@@
 ?? boost::AUescaped_list_error
```

src slightly edited to strip . in front

```
cat cpp.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"dbghelp.lib")
#define MAXLEN 0x1000
char buff[MAXLEN];
int main (int argc , char * argv[])
{
memset(buff,0,MAXLEN);
if( argc !=2 )
    {
        printf ("usage %s undemsym",argv[0]);
        exit(-1); 
    }
    char *nodot;
    if( *(char *) argv[1] == '.'  )
    {
        nodot = argv[1]+1;
    }
    else if (*(char *) argv[1] == '?')
    {
        nodot = argv[1];
    }
    else
    {        
        printf("not a valid msvc mangled name\n");
        exit(-2);
    }
    if ( ( UnDecorateSymbolName(nodot , buff,MAXLEN,UNDNAME_COMPLETE)) !=0 )
        {
            printf ("%s\n",buff);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error %x\n" , GetLastError());
        }
}
```

compile link

```
cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od cpp.cpp /link /release
```

test

```
cpp.exe
usage cpp.exe sym
cpp.exe .?AVruntime_error@stlp_std@@
.?AVruntime_error@stlp_std@@

cpp.exe ?AVruntime_error@stlp_std@@
 ?? stlp_std::AVruntime_error
```

edit for comment (add these lines to src above)

```
if ( ( UnDecorateSymbolName(nodot , buff,MAXLEN,  UNDNAME_NO_ARGUMENTS )) !=0 )
{
    printf ("%s\n",buff);
}
else
{
    printf("error %x\n" , GetLastError());
}
```

result

```
cppundem.exe .?AUescaped_list_error@boost@@
 ?? boost::AUescaped_list_error
struct boost::escaped_list_error
```

full results

```
:\cat mang.txt
.?AVFunctionBase@ns@@
.?AV?$FunctionT@P6AXPAX@Z@ns@@
.?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHH@Z@ns@@
.?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHPB_W@Z@ns@@
.?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHI@Z@ns@@
:\for /F %i in (mang.txt) do cppundem.exe %i

:\cppundem.exe .?AVFunctionBase@ns@@
 ?? ns::AVFunctionBase
class ns::FunctionBase

:\cppundem.exe .?AV?$FunctionT@P6AXPAX@Z@ns@@
?AV?$FunctionT@P6AXPAX@Z@ns@@
class ns::FunctionT<void (__cdecl*)(void *)>

:\cppundem.exe .?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHH@Z@ns@@
?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHH@Z@ns@@
class ns::FunctionT<int (__cdecl*)(int)>

:\cppundem.exe .?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHPB_W@Z@ns@@
?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHPB_W@Z@ns@@
class ns::FunctionT<int (__cdecl*)(wchar_t const *)>

:\cppundem.exe .?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHI@Z@ns@@
?AV?$FunctionT@P6AHI@Z@ns@@
class ns::FunctionT<int (__cdecl*)(unsigned int)>

:\
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your work on this; however, the resulting names are not fully correct, `AV` and `AU` are not part of the name but output in your sample.

Comment: well if you need type pass UNDNAME_NO_ARGUMENTS

Comment: I see, yeah that looks better.